# How to set request header to the ajax object for jqGrid

Tags: ajax, jqgrid

I have the need to set the 'Authorization' request header to the httpXMLRequest. On the grid definition I have tried to set via ajaxGridOptions like the following:

```
 ajaxGridOptions: { Authorization: 'Basic YWRtaW5AZGVmYXVsdC5jb206YWRTwa6=' }
```

and use the beforeSend event like the following:

```
   beforeSend:  function(jqXHR, settings) {
    jqXHR.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Basic YWRtaW5AZGVmYXVsdC5jb206YWRTwa6=');
                    }
```

None of above works for me. What's the right syntax?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use for example [loadBeforeSend](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#list_of_events) event handler of the jqGrid defined as the following:

```
loadBeforeSend: function(jqXHR) {
    jqXHR.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Basic YWRtaW5AZGVmYXVsdC5jb206YWRTwa6=');
}
```

Comment: I do see the request header being set properly in firebug by Oleg's solution.

Comment: Maybe I should put in another thread for this.. but I keep getting 401 error even the basic token is absolutely correct. If I don't set content-type in ajaxOptions, I would get 'anonymous user' at server side, after I set ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json' }, I get 401 back. I am lost...

Comment: I did post [a new thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711433/ajax-configuration-issues-for-jqgrid)

Comment: I deleted the post where I describing the authorization problem. the issue is at the server side.. has nothing to do with jqgrid

Comment: @xueru: OK! I am glad to hear this. The solved problem is the good problem.

Answer (score 1):

Another option as of today is setting the header globally for all AJAX requests:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers : {
        'Authorization' : 'Basic YWRtaW5AZGVmYXVsdC5jb206YWRTwa6='
    }
});
```

Comment: This does not seem to work in my case.  I add this global handler and it works for any $.ajax request but not for anything coming out of jqGrid.