# How to pass csrf_token to the post params of editurl of jqgrid?

Tags: javascript, python, django, jqgrid

I'm using JqGrid with Django framework. That's JS:

```
      jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
        url:'{% url views.manage.devicesajax %}',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames:['DID', 'UDID', 'Owner', 'Name', 'First seen', 'Last seen'],
        colModel :[ 
          {name:'did', index:'did', width: 30, searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','bw','cn']}}, 
          {name:'udid', index:'udid', width: 120, editable: true, searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','bw','cn']}}, 
          {name:'d_owner', index:'d_owner', width: 70, editable: true, searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','bw','cn']}}, 
          {name:'d_name', index:'d_name', editable: true, searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','bw','cn']}}, 
          {name:'d_firstseen', index:'d_firstseen', width: 80}, 
          {name:'d_lastseen', index:'d_lastseen', width: 80}],
        pager: jQuery('#pager'),
        rowNum:20,
        rowList:[20,50,100],
        sortname: 'did',
        sortorder: "desc",
        multiselect: true,
        viewrecords: true,
        imgpath: 'themes/basic/images',
        caption: 'Devices list',
        height: 330,
        width: 1000,
        onSelectRow: function(id) {
            var id = $("#list").getRowData(id).message_id;
            message_id = id;
        },
        editurl: "{% url views.manage.deviceseditajax %}"
    });
```

When I do edit row in JqGrid I get error from editurl:

> Forbidden (403)
>   CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

It's because csrf_token doesn't pass to editurl with the other data.
How to add csrf_token to the POST request to editurl ?

This code works perfectly ( complete piece of jqgrid init ):

```
     jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
        url:'{% url views.manage.devicesajax %}',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames:['DID', 'UDID', 'Owner', 'Name', 'First seen', 'Last seen'],
        colModel :[ 
          {name:'did', index:'did', width: 30, searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','bw','cn']}}, 
          {name:'udid', index:'udid', width: 120, editable: true, searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','bw','cn']}}, 
          {name:'d_owner', index:'d_owner', width: 70, editable: true, searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','bw','cn']}}, 
          {name:'d_name', index:'d_name', editable: true, searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','bw','cn']}}, 
          {name:'d_firstseen', index:'d_firstseen', width: 80}, 
          {name:'d_lastseen', index:'d_lastseen', width: 80}],
        pager: jQuery('#pager'),
        rowNum:20,
        rowList:[20,50,100],
        sortname: 'did',
        sortorder: "desc",
        multiselect: true,
        viewrecords: true,
        imgpath: 'themes/basic/images',
        caption: 'Devices list',
        height: 330,
        width: 1000,
        editurl: "{% url views.manage.deviceseditajax %}",
    });

      jQuery("#list").navGrid('#pager',{edit:true,add:true,del:true,search:true},
        {
            closeAfterEdit:true,
            reloadAfterSubmit:true,
            closeOnEscape:true,
            editData: {csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'}
        },
        {
            closeAfterAdd:true,
            reloadAfterSubmit:true,
            closeOnEscape:true,
            editData: {csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'}
        }, 
        {
            closeOnEscape:true,
            delData: {csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'}
        }, 
        {
         caption: "Search",
         Find: "Find",
         Reset: "Reset",
         sopt  : ['eq', 'cn'],
         matchText: " match",
         rulesText: " rules",
         closeAfterSearch: true,
         afterShowSearch: function ()
         {
             $('#reset_filter1_block').show();
         }
       }
      );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use Django framework and not familiar with the `csrf_token`, but after searching in Google it seems that you need to set it in the HTTP header of the request: `xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', csrf_token);`. To do this in case of jqGrid you can use [loadBeforeSend](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#list_of_events) event handler:

```
loadBeforeSend: function(jqXHR) {
    // you should modify the next line to get the CSRF tocken
    // in any way (for example $('meta[name=csrf]').attr('content')
    // if you have <meta name="csrf" content="abcdefjklmnopqrstuvwxyz="/>)
    var csrf_token = '<%= token_value %>'; // any way to get
    jqXHR.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', csrf_token);
}
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706579/how-to-set-request-header-to-the-ajax-object-for-jqgrid/5706690#5706690) for a very close problem.

**UPDATED**: To post additional data in case of form editing usage you can use `editData`: editData: { csrfmiddlewaretoken:'<%= token_value %>' }. For example:

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{},
    { // Edit option (parameters of editGridRow method)
        recreateForm:true,
        reloadAfterSubmit:false,
        closeOnEscape:true,
        savekey: [true,13],
        closeAfterEdit:true,
        ajaxEditOptions: {
            beforeSend: function(jqXHR) {
                // you should modify the next line to get the CSRF tocken
                // in any way (for example $('meta[name=csrf]').attr('content')
                // if you have <meta name="csrf" content="abcdefjklmnopqrstuvwxyz="/>)
                var csrf_token = '<%= token_value %>'; // any way to get
                jqXHR.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', csrf_token);
            }
        },
        editData: {
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: '<%= token_value %>'
        }
    },
    { // Add options (parameters of editGridRow method)
        recreateForm:true,
        reloadAfterSubmit:false,
        closeOnEscape:true,
        savekey: [true,13],
        closeAfterAdd:true,
        ajaxEditOptions: {
            beforeSend: function(jqXHR) {
                // you should modify the next line to get the CSRF tocken
                // in any way (for example $('meta[name=csrf]').attr('content')
                // if you have <meta name="csrf" content="abcdefjklmnopqrstuvwxyz="/>)
                var csrf_token = '<%= token_value %>'; // any way to get
                jqXHR.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', csrf_token);
            }
        },
        editData: {
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: '<%= token_value %>'
        }
    }
);
```

I placed here both ways: setting of 'X-CSRF-Token' HTTP header and posting of the `csrfmiddlewaretoken` parameter. You can remove one way after the corresponding experiments.

If you use some parameters for all grids on the page you can better change the defaults (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675625/setting-the-content-type-of-requests-performed-by-jquery-jqgrid/2678731#2678731) for details)

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.edit, {
    recreateForm:true,
    reloadAfterSubmit:false,
    closeOnEscape:true,
    savekey: [true,13],
    closeAfterAdd:true,
    closeAfterEdit:true,
    ajaxEditOptions: {
        beforeSend: function(jqXHR) {
            // you should modify the next line to get the CSRF tocken
            // in any way (for example $('meta[name=csrf]').attr('content')
            // if you have <meta name="csrf" content="abcdefjklmnopqrstuvwxyz="/>)
            var csrf_token = '<%= token_value %>'; // any way to get
            jqXHR.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', csrf_token);
        }
    },
    editData: {
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: '<%= token_value %>'
    }
});
```

The setting is common for both Add and Edit forms. So you can use `navGrid` in the simplified form.

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager');
```

Comment: @futureboxlab : Just now I reread your question and find out that you have problem not in filling of the grid content, but in the grid editing. So you should use `beforeSend` handler of the `jQuery.ajax` which do the same which I described in my answer. To set the event handler in case of inline editing you can use `ajaxRowOptions` option or `ajaxEditOptions` option in case of the usage of the forme editing.

Comment: I've tried it. But it sends such header when fetching records, not when it's doing POST request to the editurl.

Comment: @futureboxlab: I agree. I just wrote you the corresponding comment. If you need I could explain the same more detailed.

Comment: @futureboxlab: First of all we should clear the following question: which editing mode you use: [inline editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing) or [form editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing)? The next question: do you want to set the `X-CSRF-Token` HTTP header in all your edit requests of only in the selected one?

Comment: I use form edititng. I need it for all requests. One more thing: I'm not sure headerparam will work, but post variable will work for sure

Comment: @futureboxlab: I wrote you before that I not familiar with Django framework. Which parameter should be send`? Is it `csrfmiddlewaretoken` parameter like mhoareau suggested? Is '<%= token_value %>' the correct value or you need get it from the cookie?

Comment: I can render it into template easily like:
{{ csrf_token }} Only thing I don't know is how to send it with the editing post request.

Comment: @futureboxlab: I updated my answer. I hope now you will find the solution of your problem.

Comment: Thank you. Your solution has helped. It's important to put editData param at the correct section:
         `jQuery("#list").navGrid('#pager',
{edit:true,add:true,del:true,search:true},

            {

                closeAfterEdit:true,

                reloadAfterSubmit:true,

                closeOnEscape:true,

                editData: {csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'}


            },

    ...



           }
          );`

Answer (score 0):

Check your cookies. Django's CSRF also save a cookie `csrftoken` which does have the same value as the csrf_token which you would use in a form. You can use any Javascript cookie library to get the cookie and pass it to the POST request as `csrfmiddlewaretoken`.

Comment: I know that. It's easy to get csrftoken value. But I have no idea how to add it to the post params. Is any jqjrid method for this ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [jqGrid documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions), you can pass a **postData** options.
If you're using [jQuery Cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie), you can add something like :

```
postData: {
    csrfmiddlewaretoken: $.cookie(CSRF_COOKIE_NAME)
},
```

to your list of options to jqGrid.

The CSRF_COOKIE_NAME is set in your django application settings.py and is 'csrftoken' by default.

Comment: Unfortunately postData is sent when <i>fetching</i> records.

Answer (score 0):

I found simple solution using latest JqGrid and Inline Edit submit csrf_token to request POST django without @csrf_exempt

```
onSelectRow: function(id){
     if(id && id!==lastSel){ 
        $(selector).restoreRow(lastSel); 
        lastSel=id; 
     }

     var editparameters = {
        extraparam: {csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('.token-data').data('token')},
        keys: true,
      };
     $(selector).jqGrid('editRow', id, editparameters);

}
```

For example, please see on my blog post:
http://yodi.polatic.me/jqgrid-inline-editing-integration-with-django-send-csrf-token/