# How to Send Spring Security csrf through Jqgrig request

Tags: jquery, spring-security, jqgrid

I am Using Jqrgrid with Spring Security but how I send CSRF with JQGrid request

Comment: It's depend *which request* you mean (loading the data, editing of data and so on) and how you can get the CSRF on your client side. In some cases `$('meta[name=csrf]').attr('content')` will get you the CSRF, in another you can use `getCookie('csrftoken')`. To include CSRF in the loading request you can use `loadBeforeSend` like in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6477061/315935): `loadBeforeSend: function(jqXHR) { jqXHR.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', csrf_token); }`

Comment: yes I tried like this but still request has being forbidden.
bellow code I did.

<meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}" />
<meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}" />

var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
 var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
  $("#department-detail-grid-list").jqGrid({
  url : "${returnAllDepartmentForGrid}",
  beforeSend: function(jqXHR) {
                 jqXHR.setRequestHeader(header, token);
                },

Comment: 1) please, click on "Edit" link under the text of your question and append any additional information (like your code) to the text of the question; 2) please write *always*, which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ("free jqGrid", commercial "Guriddo jqGrid JS" or an old "jqGrid" in version <=4.7); 3) jqGrid don't have `beforeSend` callback, which you try to use. All unknown callbacks will be just ignored. You can include an `alert` message in the code of `beforeSend` to see that it will be never used. The correct name of the is `loadBeforeSend` (see my previous comment).

Comment: thankyou  loadBeforeSend is working now :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not Spring developer. The solution of your problem depends on the way how you can get the CSRF token. It seems that there are two main ways: the usage of `<meta>` with `content` equal to `${_csrf.token}` or the usage of `getCookie('csrftoken')`.

Let us we follow [the part](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-include-csrf-token-ajax) (or [this one](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/5.0.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/html5/#csrf-include-csrf-token-ajax)) of spring documentation and we add `<meta>` elements `_csrf` and `_csrf_header` as following

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}"/>
    <!-- default header name is X-CSRF-TOKEN -->
    <meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
    <!-- ... -->
</head>
<!-- ... -->
```

then we can set security token of Ajax request inside of `beforeSend` callback of `jQuery.ajax` method:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "someUrl",
    ...
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR) { 
        xhr.setRequestHeader(
            $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content"),
            $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content")
        );
    }
});
```

On the other side jqGrid *makes already internally* the Ajax request. Thus you have to use *jqGrid callbacks* to inform jqGrid to do the same inside of underlying Ajax request. Thus one should use `loadBeforeSend` callback of jqGrid:

```
loadBeforeSend: function(jqXHR) {
    var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content"),
        token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
    jqXHR.setRequestHeader(header, token);
}
```

If you would later implement editing of jqGrid data, then you will have to do close things inside of other callbacks, which allows to call `setRequestHeader` inside of `beforeSend` callback of jQuery.ajax during the editing of the grid.