# adding POST data with editgridrow

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

Apologies if this question has been answered before.

Though the answers I've seen look correct according to jqGrid documentation, I have been completely unable to get the "editData" parameter of "editGridRow" to work.

I've tried setting editData through "navGrid" edit options:

```
$("#myGrid").jqGrid(
  "navGrid",
  "#pager",
  {edit:false,add:false,del:false}, //options
  {editData:{myparam:function(){return "myval"}}}, // edit options
  {}, // add options
  {}, // del options
  {} // search options
  );
```

and through "editGridRow":

```
$("#myGrid").jqGrid('editGridRow',rowid, {
   editData:{myparam:function(){return "myval"}},
   height:240,
   reloadAfterSubmit: true,
   editCaption:'Edit Record',
   bSubmit:'Save',
   url:'someurl.php',
   closeAfterEdit:true,
   viewPagerButtons:false
});
```

My additional POST data is just NOT showing up on POST.

Any idea what I may be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right. It's a bug in [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.1.2/js/grid.formedit.js#L626)

```
postdata = $.extend(postdata,rp_ge.editData,onCS);
```

of jqGrid 4.1.2 which should be

```
postdata = $.extend(postdata,rp_ge[$t.p.id].editData,onCS);
```

If one makes the modification in the `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` all become to work correctly. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithFormEditData.htm).

By the way I could find [the fix](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/ad8e68c606327048a7421b6da0209e1c09469f62). So the bug is already fixed in the jqGrid code from the [github.com](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid).

Comment: StackOverflow has been a valuable resource for me for quite some time now, but I only joined when I had a critical issue I could not find an answer to - and as I had hoped, Oleg was on it.  jqGrid is a fine piece of software and I appreciate your help on this bug.  Not only that, I've been highly impressed with the great answers (mostly from Oleg) to other jqGrid questions on StackOverlow.  I really did look around the net for quite a while before resorting to adding a question here.  You rock Oleg!

Comment: @blitzn: You are welcome! And thank you for good words which you wrote!

Comment: Code (ver.4.4.1) from trirand.com still has this bug. Is it better idea to always use the source form github?

Comment: @volocuga: You can verify that `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` of jqGrid 4.4.1 contains the line `postdata = $.extend(postdata,rp_ge[$t.p.id].editData,onCS)`. So I can't confirm the existence of the bug in jqGrid 4.4.1.

Comment: Yep, you right I downloaded the master branch on github. I found that fix but still can't get it working. Created issue at github https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/issues/385

Comment: @volocuga: the demo which you posted use wrong option `editData`. You should `inlineData` instead or `extraparam` in case that you use inline editing. See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8512693/315935) and [another one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13035492/315935).

Comment: @volocuga: You can consider to set data like token inside of HTTP header. You can use `setRequestHeader` inside of `loadBeforeSend` (see [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5706690/315935)). Inline editing don't have any `loadBeforeSend`, but you can define `beforeSend` callback of `$.ajax` inside of `ajaxRowOptions`.

Comment: I solved my problem by this code

      $.extend($.jgrid.edit, {
        editData: {feeds_editor_token:"' . get_token() . '"}, // get_token() is a PHP function to generate a random string
        reloadAfterSubmit: true,
        closeAfterEdit:true,
        viewPagerButtons:false,
    });

Not sure if this is the right way, but at least it works form me