# correct syntax for passing additional POST data (extraparams) to server when inline editing jqGrid

Tags: jquery, post, jqgrid, inline-editing

I had a jqGrid working with inline editing with a dedicated script just for this grid.  I am trying to organize and consolidate the server scripts, so now I wish to use a new script for inline editing on the server.  To use this new script I need to pass the script an extra POST variable when editing inline.  I can't figure out how to POST additional data to server while editing inline.

With form editing I use the `editData` attribute to include addition POST data with the edit form.  I have read in the [jqGrid docs](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing) that I may be able to pass addition POST data with the `extraparams` parameter.  I just can't seem to get the syntax right.

This is what I have, and it is not working:

```
$('#list').editRow(
        id,
        true,
        function(){
            $('input[name=customer]').autocomplete({source:customerlist});
            today = new Date();
            $('input[name=date]').val(today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth()+1) + '-' + today.getDate());
        },
        extraparams={
            'arg1':'daily_folding_reports'
        }
    );
```

Where `list` is the ID of the grid.  The function to add autocomplete is firing correctly on EDIT, but I am not incorporating the `extraparams` correctly.  What is the correct syntax for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the position form of [editRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#editrow) then the call should be like the following

```
$("#list").jqGrid('editRow', id,
    true,
    function () {
        $('input[name=customer]').autocomplete({source:customerlist});
        today = new Date();
        $('input[name=date]').val(today.getFullYear() + '-' +
            (today.getMonth()+1) + '-' + today.getDate());
    },
    null,
    null,
    { arg1: 'daily_folding_reports' });
```

I personally prefer another for of the [editRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#editrow) usage which can reduce the number of `null` parameters:

```
$("#list").jqGrid('editRow', id, {
    keys: true,
    oneditfunc: function () {
        $('input[name=customer]').autocomplete({source:customerlist});
        today = new Date();
        $('input[name=date]').val(today.getFullYear() + '-' +
            (today.getMonth()+1) + '-' + today.getDate());
    },
    extraparam: { arg1: 'daily_folding_reports' }
});
```

I find the form more readable (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10396691/315935) for example).

Comment: I realize this is an old post, but would it be possible to come back and re-answer some of these based on jqGrid v4.x.x's new API?

Comment: @DevlshOne: There are too many options, so I don't full understand what you mean. There are many form of usage of inline editing: direct call of `editRow` (like here), usage of `formatter: "actions"` and usage of `inlineNav`. Moreover one can use `extraparam` with properties defined as function (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13227472/315935), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14835289/315935), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8512693/315935) and other) or one can use `serializeRowData` callback. It's just difficult to describe **all possible cases** in one answer.

Comment: I appreciate the fact that there are so many options and ways to answer this so I have posted my own specific situation and question. Thanks