# How does editData work?

Tags: php, jqgrid

JqGrid documentation states the following regarding postData:

> an array used to add content to the data posted to the server

And that's it. So, I'm using postData to send a variable to my PHP so that I can use a switch case to call the function I want.

This allows me to have a single PHP page containing all the functions for my project. I want to do the same thing with `editData` so I don't need a PHP page for every inline editing function associated with the project.

However, `editData` doesn't seem to be passing to the PHP page. I tried printing the POSTed variables to a file and they were empty. Suggestions?

Note: I am aware of the `editData` bug, but this should have been fixed by version 4.4.4 which is the one I'm using

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
    url:'functions.php',
    datatype:'xml',
    mtype:'POST',           
    postData: { 
        action:'popGrid', 
        sqlCount:sqlCount, 
        sqlSelect:sqlSelect, 
        sqlSelect2:sqlSelect2, 
        label1:label1, 
        label2:label2,
    },
    colNames:['Label','Account_Num','Amount', 'Type Code', 'Record Code',    'Sequence'],
    colModel :[
        {name:'label', index:'label', width:150, align:'center', sortable:false, editable:true},
        {name:'cntrct_id', index:'cntrct_id', width:150, align:'center', sortable:true},
        {name:'amount', index:'amount', width:150, align:'center', sortable:false, editable:true},
        {name:'type_cd', index:'type_cd', width:150, align:'center', sortable:false, editable:true},
        {name:'rec_cd', index:'rec_cd', width:150, align:'center', sortable:false},
        {name:'db_seq', index:'db_seq', width:150, align:'center', sortable:false},
    ],
    editurl: 'functions.php',
    extraparam: { action: function(){ return 'grdAdjust'; } },
    onSelectRow: function(id) {
        if(id && id!==lastSel) {
            jQuery('#list').restoreRow(lastSel);
            jQuery('#list').editRow(id,true);
            lastSel=id;
        }
    },

    pager: '#pager',
    rowNum:100,
    rowList:[100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000],
    sortname: 'cntrct_id',
    sortorder: 'desc',
    viewrecords: true,
    caption: 'Adjustments'
});
```

Comment: Do you see the outgoing POST action containing those variables in something like Firebug/Chrome? It should be as easy as passing extra data in the `editData:` parameter.

Comment: The php does not actually come up in the browser because I'm calling the php solely through jquery, so I don't think that I would be able to see the POST variables in firebug.    However, I know that the postData are being recieved (because they print to the file), whereas the editData are not.  I am sending editData thusly: editData: {actions: 'grdAdjust'},

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option `editData` play the same role in [form editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#properties) as `postData` in the main grid. On the other side you wrote about "inline editing" in the text of your question. In the case you should use `extraparam` option instead (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#saverow)). If you need to have *common* options of inline editing then probably the usage defalut settings in `$.jgrid.inlineEdit` could be helpful for you. You don't posted any code and I am not sure which editing mode and in which way you use, so I can't include more examples of usage `editData`, `extraparam` etc.

**UPDATED**: You use `extraparam` in a wrong way now. `extraparam` is **not** jqGrid option, it's option of `editRow`. Correct usage could be about the following:

```
onSelectRow: function (id) {
    if (id && id !== lastSel){
        $(this).jqGrid("restoreRow", lastSel);
        $(this).jqGrid("editRow", id, {
            keys: true,
            extraparam: {
                action: function () {
                    return 'grdAdjust';
                }
            }
        });
        lastSel = id;
    }
}
```

If you need post constant value of `action` you can use simplified form of `extraparam`: like `extraparam: {action: 'grdAdjust'}`. The usage of functions is really helpful if you need return the value of some variable or some element from the page which will be changed between different calls of `editRow`.

Additionally I would recommend you to include `gridview: true` option of jqGrid and to simplify `colModel` which you use. If `index` has the same value as `name` you can emit it. The default value of `width` is already 150, so you don't need specify `width:150` too. If you want use `align:'center'` in all or in the most columns you can change the default value of `align` for the grid by including `cmTemplate: {align:'center'}` option in the grid. Because the most column has `sortable: false` you can include the setting in the `cmTemplate` too. As the result you can reduce `colModel` to the following:

```js
colModel: [
    {name: 'label', editable: true},
    {name: 'cntrct_id', sortable: true},
    {name: 'amount', editable: true},
    {name: 'type_cd', editable: true},
    {name: 'rec_cd'},
    {name: 'db_seq'},
],
cmTemplate: {align: 'center', sortable: false},
```

Such changes simplify the code not only for reading, but for maintain too. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6047856/315935) more information about column templates.

Comment: Oleg, I posted my code above.  It shows my attempt at using extraparam based on some code I've seen around the Stack.  In answer to your question, I am specifically trying to do inline editing.  I understand that extraparam should be used with saveRow, but I'm not sure where to plug it in.

Comment: @MattWall: `extraparam` is the option of `editRow` and not the option of jqGrid. You use it in a wrong way. I'll modify my answer to include an example of correct usage.

Comment: @MattWall: I updated my answer. Don't forget to include `gridview: true` in all grids.

Comment: thanks for your help!  You went above the call of duty with that tidbit about cmTemplate.  The editparam is being recieved and printed to the file.