# jqgrid - accessing XmlHttpRequest on loadComplete event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm using jqgrid plugin in my project. It has `loadComplete` event with this description:

> `loadComplete`: *This event is executed immediately after every server request.
>   **Paramers:** data - Data from the response depending on datatype grid parameter.*

This event has only `data` as the parameter, but I need `xhr`(an instance of `XmlHttpRequest`) in this event. In fact, **I need to access `XmlHttpRequest` instance immediately after every server request.** How can I do this?

Comment: you can use beforeProcessing function witch contains xhr parameter

Answer (score 0):

**Please post the version of jqGrid and the fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7), which you use in all your questions about jqGrid.**

The callback `loadComplete` will be executed **after** the response is get from the server, the response is parsed, the current page is filled and the other data for the next pages (in case of usage `loadonce: true` option) are saved locally too. Thus you should use either `beforeProcessing` or `loadBeforeSend` or `loadError` to access to [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) object which is jQuery extension to [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#interface-xmlhttprequest).

There are different scenarios when you could need to access `jqXHR`:

- The callback `loadBeforeSend` can be used for example to set some custom HTTP headers in the request sent to the server. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5706690/315935) for the typical code example.
- `beforeProcessing` can be used to examine the server response and to modifying the `data` **before** there will be processed .
- One want to test whether there are exist pending Ajax request and to abort it for example. Free jqGrid saves the `jqXHR` object of the pending request to internal `jqXhr` parameter. One can use `abortAjaxRequest` method to abort it. The internal `jqXhr` parameter will be cleared (set to `null`) directly at the beginning of `success` processing.

If I understand your question correctly, then you can use `jqXhr` parameter directly after sending the Ajax request to the server. I'm developer of free jqGrid fork, thus I can recommend it to you. The current version of free jqGrid is 4.11.1. You can test it by modifying URLs of jqGrid to the URLs described in [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs).